# Hiding Files in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, file-attributes

I am trying to hide a whole directory, say, I have a folder named x with files y, z and folders 1 and 2 that contain, respectively, files 3 and 4... When I try to hide the whole X directory, but some files don't hide... Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you using the GUI, or the command line to try and hide the files? Do you know if you have the proper permissions to change the file attributes on all the files? You could try running the command prompt as Administrator and use the **attrib +H C:\path /S /D /L** command.

Comment: Thanks... I Did the command without the /S /D /L Part XD

Comment: @mimp You should make your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the command prompt as Administrator and use the attrib +H C:\path /S /D /L command.